# How to use LIKE in hibernate detached criteria for integer data type?

Tags: java, hibernate, model-view-controller, sql-like

I have to do `Restrictions.like("sequenceNo", "%" + Integer.valueOf(sequenceNo.trim()) + "%")`.

The field `sequenceNo` is integer type but the `sequenceNo` param value is string. My problem is I get an exception `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer`. For some reasons I really have to make my param a string data type. When I tried it in SQL to LIKE an integer it works.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: You cannot use `LIKE` with integer columns.  If you absolutely want to do this you must cast the integer to a string before the `LIKE` is applied. This would be easy if you were writing your own SQL, but right now I'm too lazy to look up how to tell Hibernate to do that :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot add Criteria`s property restrictions for the purpose, as during fetching, property value specifiedwould be casted according to the 'field type' specified in Entity class.

However, a solution would be using SQLRestriction of criteria, to by pass casting. I have tested and this works.

```
yourDetachedCriteriaObj.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction(" sequenceNo LIKE '%"+yourSequenceNumToSearch+"%' "));
```

To get list you would do like below

```
List ls = yourDetachedCriteriaObj.getExecutableCriteria(yourSession).list();
// iterate over list or do whatever.
```

Comment: without sqlRestriction is this possible. ?

Comment: another issue is i have join of tables and both table have "sequenceNo" column, in this scenario again it throws error.

Comment: this doesn't work if you want to use a alias / different table then the criteria table

Answer (score 2):

i'm ashamed, but i did following workaround with postgres

```
crit.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction(entry.getKey()+"::text like '%"+entry.getValue().replace("'", "''")+"%'"));
```

Answer (score 0):

My postgres modification

```
cr34.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction(cr34.getAlias()+"_.field::text like '%"+ fieldVal+"%'"));
```

Answer (score 0):

for Integer search parameter

criteria = session.createCriteria(demo.class).add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("sequenceNo LIKE '%"+searchParameter+"%' "));

Try this...

Answer (score 0):

```
yourDetachedCriteriaObj.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction(" sequenceNo LIKE '%"+yourSequenceNumToSearch+"%' "));
```

return error for unabling type cast:

operator does not exit : integer ~~ unknown
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument tyeps(s). you might need to add explicitr type casts.

so, we can use this code:

```
yourDetachedCriteriaObj.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction(" sequenceNo ::text LIKE '%"+yourSequenceNumToSearch+"%' "));
```